# Normalization in least-p'th minimax algorithm

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, approximation

In the book "Practical Optimization: Algorithms and Engineering Applications", the least-$p$th minimax algorithm is presented, for approximation of the minimax optimizer (Alg. 8.1):

$Loss_x(k)$ = $E(X)(\sum_{i=1}^{N} (|e_i(X)|/E(X)^p))^{1/p}$

where $E(X)=max_i(e_i(X))$ for i={1,2,...N}. So $E(X)$ is the current worst-case error of the optimizer for iteration k.

My question is why is there even a normalization by the current $E(X)$? The book mentions that they set the initial $E(X)$ to $10^{99}$. I'm guessing this is a numerical optimization issue, but I can't understand why it's needed, or even helpful.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the goal is to minimize the $p$-norm $(\sum_{i=1}^{N} |e_i(X)|^p)^{1/p}$. They rewrite it $E(X)(\sum_{i=1}^{N} (|e_i(X)|/E(X))^p)^{1/p}$, which is exactly the same thing -- the reason for this different rewriting is not entirely clear to me (probably for numerical reasons -- this ensures that all summands are in $[0,1]$, avoiding approximation errors), but this is not a renormalization -- this is the right expression to minimize.

Comment: Yes, perhaps the word "normalization" isn't right choice here. I'm basically asking how using this form avoids numerical issues (especially with the initial value of $E(X)$ being so drastically large).

Comment: Then, as written above, my best guess would be that this ensures that $\lvert e_i(X)\rvert/E(X)\in[0,1]$ for all $i$. But that's only a guess.